# How to convert two queries to an INT's and compare them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following queries, both returning one entry that's an integer.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM participants 
 WHERE `status` = 'a' 
   AND meetid = NEW.meetid) = (SELECT capacity 
                               FROM participants 
                               INNER JOIN rooms 
                                  ON pid = room 
                               WHERE room = NEW.pid)
```

I want to compare if these integers are equal, but I get MySQL error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `SELECT` before them:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participants WHERE `status` = 'a' AND meetid = NEW.meetid) = 
        (SELECT capacity FROM participants INNER JOIN rooms ON pid = room WHERE room = NEW.pid)
       ) as SameFlag
```

This assumes that the second subquery only returns one value.  Otherwise you will get an error.  This query can also be rewritten in several ways, but the above seems the smallest change to your original.

EDIT:

I am guessing that what you want is more like this:

```
SELECT (p.cnt = r.capacity)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM participants WHERE `status` = 'a' AND meetid = NEW.meetid) p CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT capacity FROM rooms room = NEW.pid) r;
```

However, it seems strange that something called `room` would be compared to `NEW.pid`.

Comment: For some reason I get error :(, but your code seems to work in editor.

Comment: I got it to work, but why does MySQL not show something useful when executing the query? Using workbench the query result is displayed as "the query".

Comment: What other approaches can I take in writing the query?